# Как сменить версию приложения в VS 10?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Приложение написано на C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В Solution Explorer
Тыкаете правой кнопкой по проекту выбираете Пропертись. Откроется окно свойств проекта, там кнопка Assembly Information.

Answer (score 1):

Можешь также в папке Properties открыть файл AssemblyInfo.cs. Там найди строку

`[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]`

Ставьте какую Вам нужно версию

Comment: Ivan, не трудитесь. Просто WarHamster не умеет принимать ответы.